# Bayes theorem Question

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose that every packet observed by a network-based intrusion detection system (NIDS) belongs to one of the following mutually exclusive categories:

- legitimate ($88\%$)
- known worm ($4\%$)
- distributed denial of service ($4\%$)
- port scan ($4\%$)

The NIDS correctly classifies all known-worm packets.

A legitimate packet is classified as legitimate with probability $91\%$, and misclassified as belonging to any of the three attack categories with equal probability.

A DDoS packet is classified as DDoS with probability $50\%$, as a known worm with probability $40\%$, and as a legitimate packet with probability $10\%$.

A port-scan packet is classified correctly with probability $85\%$, and misclassified as a legitimate packet with probability $15\%$.

If the NIDS announces that a particular packet belongs to a known worm, what is the probability that this packet is not a legitimate packet?

Let the following:

- $L$ denote the event that a given packet is legitimate
- $W$ denote the event that it is a worm
- $D$ denote the event that it is DDoS
- $S$ denote the event that it is a port scan
- $A$ denote the event that the worm alarm is raised

What I tried to is calculate $P(D\mid A)+P(W\mid A)+P(S\mid A)$.

Is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: Why $P(D|W)$ and not $P(D|A)$? Is this a typo?

Comment: What have you done to compute the quantities/probabilities you list? Have you applied Bayes rule? Show us all your work in the question description.

Comment: This is the correct approach, Pooja Gupta.  What have you tried next?    PS: @Thanassis The original post had all terms conditioned by alarm raised.  A typo crept in (now corrected).